# Expected type 'object'. Found 'void'.intelephense(1006) Issue in PHP MVC project

Tags: php, object, model-view-controller, void

Getting Expected type 'object'. Found 'void'.intelephense(1006) Issue in PHP MVC project. I attached the relevant code and source that I followed (youtube) here. Appreciate it if someone can explain what happened.

Have a home controller with a function to get an instance of a model like this: (How I coded)

```
<?php

class Controller{

    public function model($model){

        require_once '../app/models/' . $model . '.php';
        
        return new $model();
    }
    
}
```

Have User.php class like this: (How I coded)

```
<?php 


class User{
    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Have Home controller like this:  (How I coded)

```
<?php

class Home extends Controller{

    public function index($name = ''){

      
        $user = $this->model('User');
        $user->name = $name;
        echo $user->name;
        
    }

    public function test(){

        echo 'test_function()';

    }

    public function get_user_name(){

    }

    public function model($model){
        echo $model;
    }
}
```

Near the $user->name = $name; and the  echo $user->name; it shows the error. [this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iARG4.png)
I'm afraid can't find the issue. I thought it was an issue with the model but was unable to resolve it yet. I am watching a youtube video series and doing this. this is the relevant video URL [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWLXYPIxbYI&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD&index=6&ab_channel=Codecourse) Coded as here but I'm in trouble. Can someone explain why this happen and where is the error, please? I want to clarify this MVC architecture.

Answer (score 9):

You can also define your variable by adding

```
 /**
 * 
 * @var object $user
 */
```

or maybe even

```
/**
 * 
 * @var User $user
 */
```

right before

```
 $user->name = $name;
```

That should make the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you **override** the method for getting model.

Just remove the last lines in your controller.

```
public function model($model){
    echo $model;
}
```

or modify like this (but this is not necessary because this contain main Controller)

```
public function model($model){
    var_dump(parent::model($model));
}
```

this part will call model method in your controller instead of parent controller where is defined right implementation

```
$user = $this->model('User'); // this probably echo output User
$user->name = $name; // this fail
```